# BLE connectable but not scannable

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy

Is is possible to connect to a BLE device without thesaid device being discoverable?
I don't seem to have to search for a device to be able to connect to it (just knowing it's address), but I don't seem to be able to connect unless I first put the device in discoverable mode first.

I want to be able to connect to a device just knowing it's address, but that device should not appear if you scan for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the peripheral needs to be advertising before you are able to connect to it.  You can set up a white list for scan requests and connection requests, but that's about it. Depending on your specific application however, you could set up the peripheral to only broadcast its data. Alternatively, you could maintain a connection and make the peripheral enter a sleep mode until it has data to transmit.

Comment: I indeed ended up using an empty whitelist.